# Find delimiters in a string and mark that position

Tags: c#, delimiter

I'm trying to figure out how to record the position of a delimiter in a string of text entered by the user.

So if the user entered text:

orange red green yellow?

```
     *  *    *     *
```

I would want to mark the space after each word along with the question mark. (Those stars should be lining up with the delimiters.)

I know how to search the string for a certain character or set of characters, but not how I would mark it to receive a star on the next line.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: So you want to get a second string with spaces where the words are, and * at the delimiter positions? Or do you want a string with the words and * together?

Comment: Hatchet, that's exactly what I'm looking to do. I'm looking to get rid of the text and mark the delimiters only.

Comment: @user1993843: Please provide your desired result with meaningful sample data. Should the words be replaced by white-spaces(one for each character)?

Comment: @Tim: I attempted to make the above look like what I was wanting to create. My goal was to delete everything while replacing the delimiters with something significant. Words go to white-space and delimiters are stars

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "orange red green yellow?";
List<int> indexes = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\w]+").Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Index)
                        .ToList();
```

or if you want to replace delimeters with `*`

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w]+","*");
```

**EDIT**

```
var output = String.Join("",input.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c)?" ":"*"));
```

Comment: I see, that's very useful. I've never used Regex. Thanks

Comment: @user1993843 and I updated my answer according to your reply to Hatchet's comment

Comment: They're very good. I wanted to see if you knew...If I was trying to use Regex for this solution could I run two on adjacent lines of code to get the same effect, or will Regex.Replace() not run on the same string twice in a row?

Comment: @user1993843 Why don't you try it? It would take a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = text.Replace(" ", "? ");
```